# Do Amazon Lex instances have to be re-built / published each time the contents of a Custom Slot changes?

Tags: amazon-lex

The problem is a Chatbot interface to a CMS.

The content updates many times a day, and I'd like to build a "tell me about " intent.

In an ideal world, the XXX could be passed into Lambda "unchanged", but Lex can't do that. [The old "Address" trick doesn't really work any more - they seem to validate.]

So the only option seems to be to trigger a "Slot values" update from the CMS.

So, does that take affect on a published Lex intent immediately, or do we also need to rebuild the instance every time someone publishes a new thing?

Answer (score 0):

**No, it doesn't.**

It's not clear from the API what extra steps are needed to "republish", but updating a custom slot through the API does not attach it to any running intents, not even those set to "use current version of the slot."

Answer (score -1):

I'd assume at this point that Lex will rebuild itself.

Comment: Alas, your assumption proved to be wrong.... having now done it, it's not rebuilding, and it's not clear from the API what the next step is.